# SQL number to string conversion

Tags: sql, string, oracle, numbers

Here is the problem and question. Using Oracle database we have to convert user input (number) to string.
Example:

```
ACCEPT example PROMPT 'Please insert a number between  0 - 9 000 000: ';
```

User inserts number 33456
And after that we have to display result: Your chosen number was thirty-three thousand four hundred fifty-six.

Do You have ideas how to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/convert-number-into-words-oracle-sql-query/

Comment: I think the first thing you would want to do is `REVERSE()` the input. The only real difficulty would be in handling numbers where the last two digits are in the range 11-19.